# Why this Scala code returns NullPointerException?

Tags: scala

The code is:

```
def mergeTrees(t1: TreeNode, t2: TreeNode): TreeNode = {
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null) null
        else if (t1 == null) t2
        else if (t2 == null) t1

        val root = new TreeNode(t1.value + t2.value)
        root.left = mergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left)
        root.right = mergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right)

        root
}
```

And if I change it to:

```
def mergeTrees(t1: TreeNode, t2: TreeNode): TreeNode = {
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null) null
        else if (t1 == null) t2
        else if (t2 == null) t1
        else {
            val root = new TreeNode(t1.value + t2.value)
            root.left = mergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left)
            root.right = mergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right)

            root
        }
}
```

Then it works. What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chain of `if`, `else if`, `...`, conditions constitutes a single expression with a single result.

In your 1st example the `if else ...` chain results in either `null` or `t2` or `t1`. But the `if else` expression is not the only expression in the code block so, because the `if else` result is not saved anywhere then it is thrown away and processing moves on to the next expression. Which is not what you intended or want.

The 2nd code example works because there is only one expression in the `mergeTrees()` method and that is the `if else` expression. So in that case the result of the `if else` is the result of the entire method.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you have an `if` statement which calculates a value and then throws that value away.  And then it proceeds to calculate the root assuming that neither `t1` or `t2` is `null`.

The second example adds an else clause that is only used when neither `t1` or `t2` are `null`.  Now the result of the function is the result of the last statement in that function (which is the whole `if` statement).  And those values on other branches of the `if` statement are useful (they might be the last value of the function and thus the return value).

Answer (score 1):

In Scala language specification, the syntax for `def` is supported by following gremmar,

```
Def                ::=  ‘def’ FunDef
FunDef             ::=  FunSig [‘:’ Type] ‘=’ Expr
FunSig             ::=  id [FunTypeParamClause] ParamClauses
```

So, in your `def mergeTrees(t1: TreeNode, t2: TreeNode): TreeNode = {...}`, the RHS is an `Expr` and this particular syntax for `Expr` is supported by following grammar,

```
Expr               := Expr1
Expr1              := PostfixExpr
PostfixExpr        := InfixExpr [id [nl]]
InfixExpr          := [‘-’ | ‘+’ | ‘~’ | ‘!’] SimpleExpr
SimpleExpr         := BlockExpr
BlockExpr          := ‘{’ Block ‘}’
Block              ::=  BlockStat {semi BlockStat} [ResultExpr]
```

So... the parser determines your RHS to be a `BlockExpr`,

And if you read about `blocks` in Scala language specification at - https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#blocks, you will find the following explantion,

`A block expression {s1s1; ……; snsn; ee} is constructed from a sequence of block statements s1,…,sns1,…,sn and a final expression e`.

Now, what is a `block statement` of `BlockStat`?

In we just consider the following case

```
def abc(i: Int): Int = {
  i + 1
  i + 5
}
```

In this case the `i + 1` will be ignored (treated as a statement) and `i + 5` will be the return value.

Which is similar (but far simpler) to your case, then the RHS BlockExpr is parsed as following,

```
'{'
   i + 1 (BlockStat)
   i + 5 (ResultExpr)
'}'
```

But, that `i + 1` looks like an `Expr` (or Expression) then why is that treated as statment, that is because of following grammar for `BlockStat`,

```
BlockStat    ::=  Import
               |  {Annotation} [‘implicit’ | ‘lazy’] Def
               |  {Annotation} {LocalModifier} TmplDef
               |  Expr1
```

Which means any `Expr` of `Expr1` grammer can be also be treated as `BlockStat`.

So, in this case since the following,

```
{
  i + 1
  i + 5
}
```

best matches to the grammar,

```
'{'
  BlockStat
  ResultExpr
'}'
```

So, this `i + 1` which is actually an `Expr1` is treated as an `statement` and not an `expression`. Which means that it will not be the `value` of the block expression and the next `i + 5` will be tread as `value` of the block.

Now, in your case since the following `expression`,

```
 if (t1 == null && t2 == null) null
 else if (t1 == null) t2
 else if (t2 == null) t1
```

is followed by more statements, these will be treated as a `statement` and thus it will not be return value of your `def`. And further expression/statements will also be evaluated.

And since your next statement is,

```
val root = new TreeNode(t1.value + t2.value)
```

`t1.value` or `t2.value` will throw NullPointerException on evaluation in case if `t1` or `t2` is `null`.